# Using an object from an ObservableCollection as a property

Tags: c#, properties, observablecollection

I have a hypothetical situation regarding objects and properties that I'm hoping somebody can clarify for me. Say I have a class named `Employee`. Each `Employee` has an employer, which we'll call `Company`, and I have an `ObservableCollection<Company>` called `Companies` that has been populated.

`Employee` needs to be able to keep track of the `Company` that employs it. Supposing I created this property in `Employee`: `public Company Employer { get; set; }` and set it with `_employee.Employer = Companies[0]`, would that create a new, redundant instance of `Company`?

If so, is there a way to reference the appropriate instance of `Company` that `Employee` needs from `Companies` and use that as the value of its `Employer` property without creating unnecessary objects? What would be the best way to go about this (assuming I'll be creating multiple instances of `Employee`)?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Its a new reference to the same object providing they are classes not structs

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the approach I posted above or anything I need to be aware of if I use that method?

Comment: No. Maybe post some code to make it clearer, but creating a new reference to an existing object is not generally an expensive operation

Comment: I don't have any code regarding this at the moment. As I mentioned, this was a hypothetical situation I was pondering. If you'd like to propose what you've said as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a new *reference* to the same object if the types in question are classes and not structs. This is not generally an expensive operation and will not create new objects. So from what you have said I think it is ok.